# Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal multi level dictionary

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm running into an issue with creating a multi-level dictionary in Swift and have followed some of the suggestions presented here:

```
var userDict:[String:AnyObject]? = ["SystemId": "TestCompany",
                                     "UserDetails" : ["firstName": userDetail.name, "userAddress" : "addressLine1" userDetail.userAdd1]]
```

The use of `[String:AnyObject]?` works for the first level of the Dict, but Swift is throwing the same error at the next level Dict, `UserDetail[]`. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use `Any` instead of `AnyObject`

Comment: Why do you annotate a clearly non-optional dictionary as optional?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure what are the types of `userDetail.name` and `userDetail.userAdd1` but if they are Strings you should let it `[String:String]?`

However, `[String:Any]?` should solve your problem. If you are sure that you want to let it `[String:AnyObject]?` (I don't think that you want to), you can do something like this:

```
var userDict:[String:AnyObject]? = ["SystemId": "TestCompany" as AnyObject,
                                            "UserDetails" : ["firstName": userDetail.name, "userAddress" : userDetail.userAdd1] as AnyObject]
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you, Ahmad, for the answer: The user data is defined as optional Strings.  With your solution, Swift still has an issue with the "userDetails' Dict defined as AnyObject (as you suggested) stating "Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal".

Comment: by what? :) is the answer -hopefully- helped?

Comment: I resolved this by creating separate dict, setting the content,  then adding the separate dict to the main dict:

 var userDict:[String: AnyObject] = [:]
        
 userDict["systemID"] = "TestCompany"

        var userDetails:[String:String] = [:]
        userDetails = ["firstName" : userDetail.name,  "userAddress" : userDetail.userAdd1] 

    userDict["userDetails"] =  userDetails as AnyObject?